# Can I Add Discount Code To Metafield And Include In Add To Cart Button to auto apply to checkout page?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have created a new product metafield: product.metafields.my_fields.discount_code

In my product-template.liquid, there is this section:

```
<button class="btn cv_addtocart{% if section.settings.enable_payment_button %} btn--secondary{% else %} btn--primary{% endif %}" type="button" name="add" data-add-to-cart {% unless current_variant.available %}disabled="disabled"{% endunless %}>
<span data-add-to-cart-text>
                  {% if current_variant.available %}
                  {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}
                  {% else %}
                  {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
                  {% endif %}
</span>
</button>
 {% if section.settings.enable_payment_button %}
                {{ form | payment_button }}
              {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
```

I am trying to pass the value of a metafield for a product into the add to cart button. In this case, I want the discount code which is entered into the product metafield to be included.

So am hoping to do something like this:

```
 {% if section.settings.enable_payment_button %}
 {{ form | payment_button | discountCode = product.metafields.my_fields.discount_code }}
 {% endif %}
```

Basically, I am trying to automatically apply a normal discount to a product at checkout. I have seen the various shareable links that append the discount code to the url, but this does not suit my needs. Instead, I would like to retrieve the discount code (DISCOUNT20) from a metafield for that product on the checkout page and apply the coupon code there.

Any thoughts? I have been stuck on this for a long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have figured out a more reliable route:

I located my cart template liquid file and searched for a form

```
<form action="/cart" method="post" >
```

Directly below this line I inserted this

```
{%- for item in cart.items -%} 
    {%- if item.product.metafields.my_fields.discount_code.value != blank -%} 
        <input type="hidden" name="discount" value="{{item.product.metafields.my_fields.discount_code.value}}" >
    {%- endif -%} 
  {%- endfor -%}
```

In my case, value = an interpolated value being retrieved from a product metafield for the product in the cart.

FYI - you need to create a metafield in settings, then create a discount code, copy the discount code, go to your product that you want the discount code to apply to, access the product and scroll down to metafields, paste the discount code in the product's discount(if you named your metafield "discount", you might have named it something else) metafield.

Hence, as the form will be submitted with a name="discount" and value="discount_code", the checkout page will evaluate to true for discount and use the appropriate values. However this is only possible with the for loop.

For such a simple fix, I am surprised it was so hard to figure out. Hope this helps you!

---

** Some extra reading if you want: https://wearetmbr.com/shopify-auto-fill-discount-code-on-checkout-page/ **